# How to pack JSON to ZIP and unpack it back?

Tags: javascript, json, zip

JavaScript, client side.

How to pack JSON into ZIP file and unpack it back?

Thank you.

Comment: That's all? Please elaborate more. Are you talking about client side javascript or server side. What is ZIP, zip file or something else

Comment: Client side. ZIP file.

Comment: You can also try http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html

Comment: @PriyeshKumar, thank you.